# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/Log while Mocking RestTemplate with Junit

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I am writting a test case where i have to mock RestTemplate. But when i execute the test cases i am facing NoClassDefFoundException. Below is my code

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class X{
  @InjectMocks
   private YService yService;

   @Mock
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
public void test(){
  when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(),Mockito.any())).thenReturn("HelloWorld");
}
}
```

Gradle is not downloading the commons-logging dependency If i try to include it as dependency in build.gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you may be needing apache commons logging in classpath

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You are right. actually the commons-logging was excluded in my parent build.gradle, due to this the dependency was not getting resolved even when i was specifying it in my child build.gradle. So got the things working by removing the exclusion of commons-logging from my parent projects build.gradle.